# Fast parallel adding to dictionary when keys never collide

Tags: c#, dictionary, parallel-processing

I have a situation, where dictionary is created, key-value pairs are added, and after that point dictionary is used only for reading values.

I'm trying to implement quickest way of adding to dictionary in the initialization phase.

ConcurrentDictionary has very slow TryAdd method (and also GetOrAdd) - on my 6 core CPU (12 threads), CPU usage usually stays at 25%, indicating that only 3 threads are used.

It is actually faster to add all keys (around 25 million) to Dictionary sequentially, than using ConcurrentDictionary and Parallel.For.

How can I improve speed here?
It is easy to separate key-value pairs, so that keys never collide when added to dictionary, but just using code below creates some problems:

```
Dictionary<long,string> d = new Dictionary<long,string>();
d[key] = value;
```

It seems that this, when used in multi-threaded environment, fails because Dictionary does some internal changes sometimes (resizing?).

Would this work instead?

```
capacity = 250000000 //basically big enough to store all data
Dictionary<long,string> d = new Dictionary<long,string>(capacity);
d[key] = value;
```

I much prefer using Dictionary over ConcurrentDictionary, because reads are much faster too (and speed is crucial for my application).

Comment: When you say they don't collide, do you mean that they don't ever have the same value, or that they actually don't collide? Dictionaries are hash tables, and you can have a collision with two keys of different names.

Comment: Have you tried playing with `ConcurrentDictionary`'s `concurrencyLevel` constructor parameter?

Comment: @MikePrecup I mean, I can separate all keys to be added, so that each thread has unique keys to add, and every key has unique hashcode too (similar to adding numbers from 1 to 100 to dictionary - there are no duplicates or hashcode collisions)

Comment: You could try rolling your own dictionary that implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` with simplified buckets that don't have to handle collisions, can avoid collision checks, etc.

Comment: If you have 7 buckets and 10 hash codes there is no way to avoid collisions. Huge memory intensive operations not necessary will be improved by running on multiple threads - if single thread `Dictionary` is fast enough - just stick to it (since you don't need locking on read if there is no writes).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the maximum size of the dictionary, then yes you can improve speed by pre-allocating. However, that won't prevent concurrent adds from potentially messing up your dictionary. Internal lists are updated, and it's quite possible for two threads to end up storing the key at the same index in a list.

Have you tried the obvious thing? That is:

```
lock (dictionaryLock)
{
    dict[key] = value;
}
```

If the lock is not contended, it's going to take perhaps 20 nanoseconds. If it *is* contended, then the delay is slightly longer, but you're doing a very short operation. Whether this will be faster will depend a lot on what kind of processing is done between calls to `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

Jim's suggestion is great. However, that's probably the fastest you can go without any significant effort. It's also an obvious approach which I believe you should have considered on your own. Assuming you're still not comfortable with the efficiency and the level of concurrency, here's an idea borrowed from 2-level page table:

1, come up with a criterion to break your large dictionary into a bunch of smaller ones.

2, store the 2nd level dictionaries in a static container, so that no run time self-organization can possibly break the premises of concurrent access.

3, come up with a fast mapping algorithm to jump directly to any 2nd level dictionary.

As a very specific example without any benchmarking: In your case, you can consider an array of 250 elements, each being a reference to a dictionary which in turn holds 100k strings. You need to come up with an algorithm that maps long to the index of the array. A simple one can be long % 250. Again, this may require some benchmarking to arrive at the most efficient solution.

The idea behind this proposal is:

1) A dictionary has an optimal capacity, beyond which the underlying hash function may see more collisions.

2) Allow for concurrency as much as possible - in the proposal, you'll need 250 locks, one for each 2nd level dictionary.

3) Most importantly, with some effort in benchmarking and implementation, you can extend the idea to multi level dictionaries - as is the case with multi level page table.